# Error calling (click) function inside ngIf else template

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I have an `*ngIf` with an `else` template defined as such:

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="!paused; else resume" (click)="pause()">
    pause
</button>

<ng-template #resume>
    <button type="button" (click)="resume()">
        resume  
    </button>
</ng-template>


class AppComponent  {
    paused = false;
    pause() {
        this.paused = true;
    }
    resume = () => {
        this.paused = false;
    }
}
```

The pause button works, but clicking the resume button will log a console error:

> Error: jit_nodeValue_4(...) is not a function

[Here is a runnable demo of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-demo-94ha7r). Click the 'Resume' button and check console for errors.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the inline template `resume` conflicts with the method name `resume`. The template basically overwrites the method, hence the error.

If you change the template name, it will work:

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="!paused; else resumeTpl" (click)="pause()">
  pause
</button>

<ng-template #resumeTpl>
  <button type="button" (click)="resume()">
    resume  
  </button>
</ng-template>
```